# jQuery Easing function not working here

Tags: javascript, jquery

File Reference(Master Page):

```
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JavaScript/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#bookmark1" class="rightLinks">Go to 50s</a>
<a id="bookmark1" class="title">50s</a>
```

Code in JavaScript.js file

```
 $(".rightLinks").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: (($(id).offset().top) - 30) }, 300, "easeOutCubic");
});
```

when i remove 'easeOutCubic' it works perfectly:

```
 $(".rightLinks").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: (($(id).offset().top) - 30) }, 300");
});
```

But why not with the easing function?

Answer (score 0):

add this library [**jquery.easing.min.js**](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js):

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

add with your libraries:

```
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="JavaScript/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="JavaScript/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

#### [A demo of easing](http://jsfiddle.net/b2GaA/)

Answer (score 0):

You must need to add reference of `jQuery UI 1.10` in your master page, that's it!

You can download it from here http://jqueryui.com/download/